# Problems with implementation of unique_ptr's move constructor

Tags: c++, move-semantics, unique-ptr, move-constructor

I'm trying to write a unique_ptr implementation. I'm struggling with writing a move constructor. Here are my problems:

1. When I mark the move constructor as `default`, my resource is deleted twice, when I move assign a pointer (`auto foo2 = std::move(foo);` below) - why?
2. When I'm trying to assign the underlying pointer in the move constructor like this `*rhs = nullptr` (see implementation below), the compiler says `*rhs` is an rvalue and that I cannot assign anything to it.
3. Finally, `rhs.m_ptr = nullptr` works. Why does it work, when `*rhs = nullptr` doesn't?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace my
{
template <class T>
class unique_ptr
{
public:
    unique_ptr()
    {
        m_ptr = new T;
    }
    unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
    // move constructor
    unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& rhs)  // = default deletes m_ptr twice
    {
        m_ptr = *rhs;
        rhs.m_ptr = nullptr;  // *rhs = nullptr doesn't work (*rhs is an rvalue)
    }
    ~unique_ptr()
    {
        delete m_ptr;
    }
    T* operator->()
    {
        return m_ptr;
    }
    T* operator*()
    {
        return m_ptr;
    }
    unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
    // no move assignment yet
private:
    T* m_ptr;
};

}  // namespace my

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "~Foo" << std::endl;
    }
    void printHello()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    my::unique_ptr<Foo> foo;
    foo->printHello();

    auto foo2 = std::move(foo);

    return 0;
}
```

On a side note, apparently I can pass a unique_ptr without any template parameter to methods inside the unique_ptr class template. Does compiler just assume it's T?

Please discard any other implementation faults that don't relate to the described problems. It's work in progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) The default move constructor doesn't know about the semantics of your class. So it moves the pointer `rhs`, but it will not reset the other pointer, which will get deleted as well in the other destructor.

2) `*rhs` calls `operator*` and returns a temporary/rvalue `T*`, a copy of the internal pointer, and is not consistent with the usual `operator*` which should return a `T&` or a `const T&`.

3) see 2. you are returning a temporary object.

So finally, what you should have:

```
unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& rhs)  // = default deletes m_ptr twice
: m_ptr(rhs.m_ptr)
{
    rhs.m_ptr = nullptr;  // *rhs = nullptr doesn't work (*rhs is an rvalue)
}

T& operator*() {return *m_ptr;}
const T& operator*() const {return *m_ptr;}
```

And so on.

Comment: The **constructor** should not delete its pointer, since that pointer doesn't point at anything sensible.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, messed up with the assignment... Also move it to the initialization list. Thanks a lot for checking!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying too hard. You don't have to go through the external interface. Just assign values:

```
m_ptr = rhs.m_ptr;
rhs.m_ptr = nullptr;
```

In addition, `operator*()` should return a `T&`, not a `T*`.